# VB6 WinHttpRequest "PUT" - Modify Request Header

Tags: vb6, httprequest

I'm trying to access an API via VB6.
I'm successfully able to  "POST" AND "GET".

Now running into problems with "PUT"
I'm able to "PUT" using Postman but cannot get it to work in my VB6 Code (able to "GET" and "POST" though)

If i do a 
objWinHttp.GetAllResponseHeaders
I get:

```
 **Allow: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD**
 Content-Length: 2
 Content-Type: application/json
 Server: cloudflare
 Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dade65e860f9164a08757164f49c2c6ce1524753607; expires=Fri, + 26-Apr-19 14:40:07 GMT; path=/; domain=.monday.com; HttpOnly; Secure
 Status: 405 Method Not Allowed
 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
 X-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass
 X-Request-Id: 55aba84b06aaaf03f1e4127ddf9a603a
 X-Runtime: 0.009866
 X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
 Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
 CF-RAY: 4119cd7c1f1571d9-ORD
```

I'be tried modifying the Header "Allow" by using

```
ObjWinHttp.SetRequestHeader "Allow", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
```

and

```
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"
```

to no luck

Any ideas as to why I can't allow PUT requests or another reason this won't work.

Comment: Please format your post to make it more readable (Bold, italic, list , code indentation etc) Use code block (Ctrl+K) instead of Quotes (>>)

Comment: Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Is the code [marked and indented properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90408/316262)? Are there enough paragraphs? If it doesn't, work on it until you feel like it is easy to read and understand. Also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to write good questions. Use the [edit] button to improve your question. This will increase your chances of someone actually answering your question a great deal!

Comment: @Prateek feel free to copy (and adapt) my canned response if you like it. Also I can recommend  AutoReviewComments as a browser extension

Comment: @Prateek If you are looking for more, I put all of my canned responses here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366642/4298200

Answer (score 0):

You can't demand that the server change itself by trying to send a response header as a request header.  The server may not be able to process a PUT method at all anyway rather than simply disallowing them.

For a normal simple-minded page-serving web server a PUT is an attempt to replace a static page, server-side script, or other resource.  Why would they ever allow just anybody to hack them like that?